# List Distributions default programs with short description

Tags: package-management

I was wondering How one can list (or if there is an online list) of most important/popular (alternatively all) default installed programs/packages in ubuntu?
I know how to list packages, but many I don't know what they do.

Something like this, but for the actually installed system (in my case 13.10):
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListOfOpenSourcePrograms

Is it possible to generate, of course maybe not by category?

thanks!
T

Comment: There's really no list with descriptions anywhere, that's the closest thing we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all software that is installed on your system (also default installed software) open a terminal and type:

```
root@host:~# dpkg --list
```

In the second column you have the name of the package and in the fourth column the short description.

You can also perform a search in the list of available packages (names and descriptions will be matched). But those packages are available to install on your system.

```
root@host:~# apt-cache search firefox
firefox - Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
firefox-branding - Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla - transitional package
firefox-dbg - Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla - debug symbols
...
```

The first column is the package name and the second is the shotr description.

Comment: Hm, yes, thanks. I don't know what command I had found before that I didn't see the short description. But now it made me think of even a quick hack to find packages by 'categories':


dpkg -all |grep searchword

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Dash, the Application lens, and then Installed.

For an actual list, try `dpkg- l`.